# YouTube app stops loading

Tags: youtube

Device: Xperia V
Android: Stock ROM, rooted

When I watch some YouTube video on the YouTube app, it plays up to some point. Then, it just shows that it loads, and never continues. Why is that?

Comment: Are you using YouTube app, or stock browser?

Comment: I am using the YouTube app

Comment: What happens when you access YouTube via your browser? (Assuming you're currently using Wi-Fi) did you try using 3G/4G to access YouTube

Comment: And did you try `Main Menu > Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > YouTube > Clear Data`?